# disable notification to connect to a USB Function Filesystem in Android 7.0

Tags: usb, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

We have written an android application that communicates with a piece of custom hardware over USB.  Prior to Android 7.0 Nougat when we plugged in the usb the app would lauch automatically and establish a ptp connection between the two devices.  Now in Android 7.0 the app no longer launches automatically.  Instead a USB symbol appears in the upper left corner.  Pulling down the notifications window shows a notification that reads as follows:
Android System
Connected to USB Function Filesystem
Tap to view files

How can we avoid having this permissions notification pop up before starting our app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an OS configuration question and not a programming question. It may be more suitable for [android.se] instead.

Comment: This is a an android application programming question.  I'm asking what permissions or other settings in my app need to be set to override the new permission/notification window.  I don't want users to have to make any changes to their OS configuration to continue to use my app.